# Retrieve channel's info using youtube data API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to fetch Youtube channel information e.g. total number of subscribers, language, info tab etc. What's the endpoint to do so if I have only my API key and channel id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the answer, following is the API call to fetch channel information.

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet,statistics&id=UCSJ4gkVC6NrvII8umztf0Ow&key=[API_KEY]

Google's API Doc 
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/youtube.channels.list/m/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list

Answer (score 0):

using of below link which i shared might be useful for your problem

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list